# How to pass data between fragments in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have MainActivity and four fragments in viewPager. I need to send some strings from the first to the third fragment. But i can't. I've tried a lot of ways, but unsuccessfully. I tried with interface but unsuccessfully....any Help?

Comment: You can user EventBus or Otto event bus. Is quite simple.

Comment: Can you give me example?

Comment: https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus ..there are examples given within ..it is easy to do ..just check the examples and u will get an idea

Answer (score 0):

An idea:

```
public class MessageEvent {
   public String message;
}

class ThirdFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EventBus.register(this);
    }

    public void onEvent(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
        LOG.d("Message event", messageEvent.message);
        /* Process your message */
    }; 
}


class FirstFragment extends Fragment {


    void sendMessageEvent(MessageEvent messageEvent){
        EventBus.getDefault().post(MessageEvent);
    }
}
```

Comment: i have this error: Unable to resolve virtual method 11969: Lde/greenrobot/event/EventBus; . post